# <Server> <BEA-002611> <The hostname " ", maps to multiple IP addresses: 10.253.254.83, 10.0.75.1, 192.168.1.15, 172.17.120.193

Tags: spring, weblogic

EA-002613>  
<09.Ara.2019 20:10:36,792 EET>     
<09.Ara.2019 20:10:36,792 EET>     
<09.Ara.2019 20:10:36,793 EET>     
<09.Ara.2019 20:10:36,814 EET>     
<09.Ara.2019 20:10:36,815 EET>     
<09.Ara.2019 20:10:36,815 EET>     
<09.Ara.2019 20:10:36,816 EET>     
<09.Ara.2019 20:10:36,815 EET>     
<09.Ara.2019 20:10:36,816 EET>     
<09.Ara.2019 20:10:36,816 EET>     
<09.Ara.2019 20:10:36,817 EET>     
<09.Ara.2019 20:10:36,817 EET>     
<09.Ara.2019 20:10:36,819 EET>

Comment: Can you please add your question?

Answer (score 0):

From the Title I think you want to know why "" is mapping to multiple IP Addresses in Weblogic. If you don't provide Hostname/IP in Listen Address then Weblogic will listen to all available addresses. So your Weblogic Server is listening on all IP available IP addresses.